# How merge or Concatenating two midi files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, midi

I am working on a project which is producing midi files as output. But those midi files are very short and i want to merge or concatenate them to produce a single long midi file. I am using [python-midi library](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) and there is not so much information or documentation about this library. I tried with this program but its giving error :

```
import midi
pattern=midi.read_midifile("kl.mid")
track=midi.Track()
pattern2=midi.read_midifile("oi.mid")
pattern.append(pattern2)
midi.write_midifile("aaka.mid",pattern)
```

error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lp.py", line 6, in <module>
    midi.write_midifile("aaka.mid",pattern)
  File "/home/userdf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/midi/fileio.py", line 152, in write_midifile
    return writer.write(midifile, pattern)
  File "/home/userdf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/midi/fileio.py", line 102, in write
    self.write_track(midifile, track)
  File "/home/userdf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/midi/fileio.py", line 116, in write_track
    buf += self.encode_midi_event(event)
  File "/home/userdf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/midi/fileio.py", line 125, in encode_midi_event
    ret += write_varlen(event.tick)
AttributeError: 'Track' object has no attribute 'tick'
```

I googled a lot but have not found a way to add two midi files via python. 
Let me know how can i do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the full stack trace? It should tell you what line the error is at.

Comment: @twasbrillig , I have edited the question with more information.

Comment: maybe you can convert your midi file to make the manipulation easier... ? do you know http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/ ? .... also you can use https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/midi_files.html#opening-a-file and read each midi message in each file and re-write the in the third file.... ?

Answer (score 1):

read the midi files and save the patterns

```
pattern1 = midi.read_midifile(file1)
pattern2 = midi.read_midifile(file2)
```

then read each track from each pattern

```
pattern = midi.Pattern()

for track in pattern1:
    pattern.append(track)

for track in pattern2:
    pattern.append(track)
```

finally save the file with new pattern

```
midi.write_midifile('sound.mid', pattern)
```

Comment: Combining midi files with this method seems to actually play the two patterns simultaneously (instead of concatenated, which OP requested).

Comment: That makes sense, those tracks will include timing data per event, so they're all still playing at the same time. OP would need to offset the event times of the track events to have them play sequentially. The appending behaviour however is exactly what _I_ need, so thanks for that!